# How to extract x lines every y number of lines

Tags: bash, sed, tail

I have a big file from which I want to extract x lines every y number of lines. I searched around and found some answers on how to print the first z lines, something like `tail -n +<lines to skip + 1>` 
I'm trying to combine it with sed but don't know how.

Comment: You mean extract lines [1...x], drop lines [x+1...y], extract lines [y+1...y+x], drop [y+x+1...2y], and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print the first two lines of every tex lines, try:

```
awk -v x=2 -v y=10 '(NR - 1) % y < x'
```

For example:

```
$ seq 20 | awk -v x=2 -v y=10 '(NR - 1) % y < x'
1
2
11
12
```

#### How it works

Awk reads through the input line-by-line.  It will print the line if the condition `(NR - 1) % y < x` is true.  `NR` is the line number starting at one for the first line.

Comment: Great explanation on how it works. I also learned the command `seq 20`.

Answer (score 1):

I like the awk answer, but if you must use sed:

```
sed -n 'p;n;p;n;p;n;n;n'
```

This would write 3 and then skip 3. Each ''p'' writes the current line, then the ''n'' grabs the next.

I wouldn't recommend it for high values of x and y since it will get long.